# How to broadcast real time events to external application

Tags: laravel, socket.io

I'm working on a project where Laravel is the back-end and front-end is a ReactJS. I'm responsible for back-end only and we are building back-end as a restful api, so I'm using sanctum to authenticate user, there are no sessions, stateless flow. Now I need to implement a real time in web notifications. I was thinking about using Laravel Broadcasting: Redis + Laravel echo server. But the problem is, that frontend is not made on laravel. Its a simple ReactJS SPA, that uses back-end as an API.

My question is what is the best way to implement this functionality? I guess listening to standard events from that ReactJS app is not going to work?

Comment: Do you use a building tool such as Laravel Mix or Webpack?

Comment: No, Because Laravel is used only for back-end, I do not use anything related to front-end, even blade files is not used.

Comment: Yes, but if you use an assets building tool, no matter which, you could use Laravel Echo which is nothing more than a NPM package and `require` it in a JS file you would build then.